# Program didn't see DLL file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll

I'm making a programm on C# language and i'm using a special Dll file where storing class with methods that i'm using. At the project i added Dll file as a reference and then print `using "library_name"` at the code. It's perfectly work on my computer where i'm making it (where is visual studio) and it's also great working on another computer. But my program didn't working at virtual machine that located on second computer. When i'm trying to open it i had an exception like:
"Could not load file or assembly 'spd_lib, Version=1.0.4244.21567, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null" or one it's dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Somewhere i read that `.csproj` file had a string where storing all the project's references, so i tried to modify it and give absolute path to the library that located on virtual machine, but it didn't working anyway and had the same exception. Can you please recommend me something to do with it ?

Forgot to say, that my program is on WInForms, so it's perfectly opening and working on virtual machine, but when i press button (there is event where i declare an object of class that located at Dll file) it's had exception and crashed. So, i'm afraid it's not .Net framework problem :/

Comment: Did you copy the whole `bin\Release` folder? Did you try to copy it into another location on your machine and start it from there?

Comment: You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). Filter the view to your process only and watch out for *FILE NOT FOUND* errors.

Comment: Oliver, yes, i copy all bin\Release folder. Actually i also tried to copy all the solution folder. But unfortunatelly it's still doesn't working. So, I'll try to use the programm that you recommend, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The virtual machine where you are hosting the application, does it have .Net framework installed?
There are system dlls which are installed in your machine as you have visual studio installed, but the virtual machine might be missing those.

Comment: Yes, It has a .Net framework  4.0. And program didn't find only library where locating methods that i need. Forgot to say, that my program is on WInForms, so it's perfectly opening and working, but when i press button (there is event that's where i declare an object of class that located at Dll file) it's had exception and crashed. So, i'm afraid it's not .Net framework problem :/

Comment: Okay, are you using any dependency injection for that class object?

Comment: no. I just only using this dll file where class is storaging, and no other dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The dll has to be present on the Virtual machine in order for your program to work. To do it you have to mark it as `Copy Local` in the Visual Studio Preferences window for this particular dll (press F4 when your reference is selected) - when you do it it will be copied to the bin folder (or to any other folder when you Publish your application).

[image]

If it doesn't work you need to check from where the application requests this file. For this task you can use [fuslogvw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) or just check it with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx).

Comment: Yes, i using to "copy local" setting, and it's still doesn't working. I will try to use the programs, that you recommend, to check application requests. Dziekuje!

Comment: @Ramon Also focus on this part of the error too: "or one it's dependencies" it might be the case that the dll is there but one of the dll's that is required by the 'spd_lib' is missing.

Comment: it's weird, but no, it's only one library and there's no other dependencies for it. I installed on virtual machine visual studio and everything magically starting to work ! I haven't got any idea, why it's happening, it shouldn't be so, just weird :/ But thank you for helping!

Comment: so if after installing VS everything works there has to be some dependency on the dll's that are delivered with VS. I think what you should do (if you want to get the root cause) is to run under Process monitor w/o VS and w/ VS installed and compare the traces. There you should see what dll is problematic.

Comment: Okay! Thanks Pawel!